# Retain scroll position after Vaadin Grid update

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am experimenting with Vaadin 7.5, using a Grid to show a number of rows (few hundred) and send periodic updates (1 update/sec for the full data-set) via push (AUTO).

The update works fine, but I am having troubles with the scrollbar. With each update the table scrolls back to the first row.

*I would like to do these refreshes without any scrolling. Is there a setting or at least a workaround for this?*

The two different approaches for data-update:

1.

```
    BeanItem<Instrument> item = container
            .getItem(container.getIdByIndex(new Random().nextInt(container.size() - 1)));
    item.getItemProperty(MARGIN).setValue(updated.getMargin());
    item.getItemProperty(EXPOSURE).setValue(updated.getExposure());

    grid.markAsDirty();
```

2.

```
    if (update instanceof List) {
        List<Instrument> updates = (LinkedList<Instrument>) update;
        for (Instrument updated : updates) {
            Instrument item = currentData.get(new Random().nextInt(currentData.size() - 1));
            item.setMargin(updated.getMargin());
            item.setExposure(updated.getExposure());
        }
    }
    container.removeAllItems();
    container.addAll(currentData);
```

These solutions perform differently depending on the number of records being updated, but both shows the unwanted feature of scrolling back to the top of the list with every update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SSCCE works for me on Vaadin 7.5.10:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    BeanContainer<Long, DecemberBean> dataSource = new BeanContainer<Long, DecemberBean>(DecemberBean.class);
    Grid grid = new Grid(dataSource);
    Runnable r = () -> {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("update");
            try{Thread.sleep(2000);}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();};
            UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
                for (Long item : dataSource.getItemIds()) {
                    DecemberBean k = dataSource.getItem(item).getBean();
                    k.setNumber(k.getNumber() + 100);
                }
                grid.sort(grid.getContainerDataSource().getContainerPropertyIds().iterator().next());
            });
        }
    };
    dataSource.setBeanIdResolver(bean -> new Long(bean.getNumber()));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        dataSource.addBean(new DecemberBean(i));
    }
    setContent(grid);
    new Thread(r).start();
}
```

However, I had to use `grid.sort()` instead of `markAsDirty` to refresh the state of component. I haven't noticed any scrolling at all.